# Animation does not end completely

Tags: html, css

I have a text slide but it finishes before sliding completely, the element with the texts is position: absolute and left: 100%. I apply an animation in it that goes from left: 100% to left: -100%, it was expected that all the element would move out of the right >> going out by the left, which in fact happens, but before the total displacement happens, the sliding ends.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif
}

.news-wrapper {
 height: 50px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-size: 25px;
 padding: 10px 0 0
}

.news-wrapper .footer-item {
 display: flex;
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: rebeccapurple;
 list-style: none;
 left: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 animation: sliding 20s linear;
 white-space: nowrap
}

.news-item {
 margin-right: 100vw
}

.news-item:last-child {
 margin: 0
}

@keyframes sliding {
 100% {
  left: -100%
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="news-wrapper">
  <ul class="footer-item">
    <li class="news-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, maxime?</li>
    <li class="news-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, maxime?</li>
    <li class="news-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, maxime?</li>
    <li class="news-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, maxime?</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is depends on your time that you specify in your CSS

Comment: The 100% are calculated based on the outer element and not based on its contents. In your case the text length exceeds the outer element's width so when it reaches `left: -100%`, rests of the text are still inside the view port. You would need to move it farer off the screen e.g. by moving it to `left: -150%;.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% refers to the parent div (the relative div)

Your not moving the text far enough. In your sliding animation, have `left: 0;` and `transform: translateX(-100%);`

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/metaDesign/v5dfa4mg/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to animate using left property which is not relative to the element itself. In your code left in percentages is relative to window width. So left -100% to 100% means -100% to 100% of the window width. 
Instead of left use transform: translate(0, 100%) to transform: translate(0, -100%)

```
@keyframes sliding {
 0 {
   transform: translate(-100%, 0);
 } 100% {
   transform: translate(100%, 0);
 }
}
```